# Как программно получить путь к директории, в которую установлен продукт?

Tags: windowsinstaller, c#

Создаём объект класса Installer. У него есть свойство Products. Оно возвращает список гуидов установленных продуктов. Чтобы получить производителя и название продукта, мы вызываем Installer.get_ProductInfo, передавая ему полученный гуид и имя свойства. Работает. Но найти способ получения директории, в которую фактически установлен продукт, не получилось.

Comment: А InstallLocation (ARPINSTALLLOCATION) - это разве не то, что Вам нужно?

Comment: Это метод чего? Если это экспортируемая функция, то какой dll? Какого типа передаваемый параметр?<br><br>
installer.get_ProductInfo(productGuid, "InstallLocation") возвращает пустую строку.

Comment: Если инсталлятор Ваш, то можно добавить Custom Action, который пропишет в ARPINSTALLLOCATION значение TARGETDIR во время установки и возвращаемое значение не будет пустым. Если не Ваш, то этот способ не подойдет, поскольку большинство инсталляторов по умолчанию это свойство не прописывают.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще, детерминированно это сделать нельзя. Инсталлер-то конечно знает где программа установлена, но я не думаю что у него можно взять и спросить. Естественно на вопрос "откуда он знает" ответ обычно такой - это прописано в реестре. Поэтому если знаете путь в реестре, то берите оттуда, если нет - я бы пробовал методом тыка то есть `if Directory.Exists(@"c:\program files\x") then ... else if (Directory.Exists(@"c:\program files (x86)\x")...` и так далее.

Answer (score 0):

При установке помещаются ключи в реестре. Посмотрите там должно быть. Если нет - заводите при установке ключ.

Comment: Начальник говорит, что так неправильно. Такое решение будет зависеть от реализации инсталлятора, а если использовать WindowsInstaller, он сам разберётся, в каком месте искать нужную информацию.